# Read common name from .pem file

Tags: shell, ssl, certificate

is there a way to read the common name from a .pem file in my shell?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us how the .pem was created, and confirm this is about x509 certificates?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First off, the `.pem` extension only refers to the type of encoding used in the file.

The common name would be a feature of the Subject or Issuer of a certificate, and can be recognised by the lines

```
$ grep CERTIFICATE f.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and lots of base64 encoded text in between.

If the `.pem` file contains an [x509 certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), 
this should do the trick:

```
openssl x509 -in cacert.pem -noout -text
```

This will dump the whole certificate.  The [`openssl x509`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/x509.html)
 command has several options to suppress the fields you don't want to see.  You find those explained in the man page, under [`TEXT OPTIONS`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/x509.html#Text-Options)

You can also choose to get shown just the 'Subject' of the certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in cacert.pem -noout -subject
```

---

Example:

Let's capture the certificate of `stackoverflow.com` straight from the server

```
$ : | openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443 > f.pem 2>& 1 &&
      openssl x509 -in f.pem -noout -subject 2>& 1
```

Outputs:

```
Subject: CN = *.stackexchange.com
```