# How can I retrieve a certificate's expiration date?

Tags: ios, macos, security

I'm attempting to write a script to keep an eye on my battery of signing credentials for a build server I'm running. I'm almost positive I can accomplish this in a bash script using security(1), but I can't find any examples on how to find expiration information of installed identities in a given keychain (everything looks encrypted).

Has anyone done something similar that might be able to help me get these dates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use the `find-certificate` command line option with security(1), you can output the certificate in PEM format with `-p`.

From there, use `openssl x509 -text` to output the fields from the certificate. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793528/read-common-name-from-pem-file) You should be able to play with options and text output to get the data you need from there.

Comment: Thanks Adam!  This is the most complete answer to help me automate this.

Comment: It's very annoying that there's no way to find certificates by some unique value. Names don't have to be unique, unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 2):

Why not getting it with **openssl** (x509 --help)

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -in cert.pem -enddate
```